# Democracy in GRRMs world

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Given that The Six Kingdoms are a democracy (of sorts), is there any history in the GRRM world of any other democracies?

Comment: not sure but i don't think so. All 7 kingdoms have a Lord (the dominant house), thus is monarchy/feudalism

Comment: also, it's not democracy, it's elective monarchy

Comment: @Kepotx I don't think it's a duplicate, since it's not just about the Iron Throne

Comment: Elective Monarchy isn't democracy. And it is an idea native to westeros since ancient days of First Men migration. First men chose their early kings and chieftains via votes, every free man had a right to speak. Ironborn still raise their Kings through popular vote at Kingsmoot although there are long periods of disruptions when hereditary monarchy kicks in. Free Cities would be closest to democracy where Freeholders and rich folks get a vote.

Comment: @Aegon even for the free city, it's more oligarchy than democracy, similar to Maggior Consiglio with only rich family that rule

Comment: @Kepotx Yup, hence the closest. All you need to vote is to be a free man and own property inside the city. Which is as close as it gets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Night's Watch

The Night's Watch is somewhat of a democracy. They elect their Lord Commanders by majority vote. The Lord Command then rules for life, so whether this is really democracy can be questioned.

Why Samwell Tarly didn't mention this habit to strengthen his case during his suggestion in the final episode, one can only guess; it seems he has had some first-hand experience, but seems to have kind of forgotten.

> Sam, you're a sweet fool, he could hear Jon saying, all the way back to the maester's keep. Open your eyes. It's been happening for days. Could he be right? A man needed the votes of two-thirds of the Sworn Brothers to become the Lord Commander of the Night's Watch, and after nine days and nine votes no one was even close to that. Lord Janos had been gaining, true, creeping up past first Bowen Marsh and then Othell Yarwyck, but he was still well behind Ser Denys Mallister of the Shadow Tower and Cotter Pyke of Eastwatch-by-the-Sea. One of them will be the new Lord Commander, surely, Sam told himself.
>   <sub>A Storm of Swords - Samwell IV</sub>

## Volantis

The Volantese also have elections, but there is no universal right to vote. These officials are elected for short terms.

> "The triarchs are neither kings nor princes. Volantis is a freehold, like Valyria of old. All freeborn landholders share the rule. Even women are allowed to vote, provided they own land. The three triarchs are chosen from amongst those noble families who can prove unbroken descent from old Valyria, to serve until the first day of the new year. And you would know all this if you had troubled to read the book that Maester Kedry gave you."
>   <sub>A Dance with Dragons - The Merchant's Man</sub>

## Iron Islands (sometimes)

When they feel like it, the Ironborn of the Iron Islands elect their king in a Kingsmoot. Similarly to the Night's Watch it is questionable whether electing someone to rule as "tyrant" is really democracy, but it's another example of "voting for your ruler" as Sam intended.